# diag_part shape issue in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Running from master the following code gives an error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

W = tf.constant(3., tf.float64)
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [5,3])
Y = tf.scalar_mul( W , tf.ones(tf.pack([tf.shape(X)[0], tf.shape(X)[0]]), tf.float64) )
Z = tf.diag_part(Y)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(Z, feed_dict={X: np.ones((5,3))}))
```

The relevant part of the error is

> /tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 960, in _DiagPartShape
>       " do not match ")
>
> **ValueError**: Invalid shape, shape[:mid] (?,) and shape[mid:] (?,) do not match

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I have also asked this quesiton on tensorflow discuss here: https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/qQKrS10Aops

Comment: if I copy-paste this, I get syntax error. If I fix it, I get different error, problem with Rank on tf.scalar_mul line

Comment: Hi @YaroslavBulatov . Thanks for looking into this. My apologies I stupidly made a mistake when copying the problem into Stack Overflow format-. I've gone back and done it correctly and corrected my original post. I'm using TensorFlow git hash b2f6d500c15eaea56d1855c7c047184cdf455a19 which I pulled from master and compiled this morning and I get the error I have described. Any ideas?

Comment: I have posted this as a big on github.

Comment: How about a link to the bug post?